# Integral Equality or Inequality

Tags: integration, measure-theory, operator-theory

I am reading Stein's paper "On Limits of Sequences of Operators", but I am stuck on something that should be simple. Reduced to precisely where I'm stuck:
$$F\left(t\right)=\sum_{N_1}^{N_2}b_nr_n\left(t\right)\text{,}$$
where $r_n\left(t\right)$ are the Rademacher functions defined as: $r_n\left(t\right)=r_0\left(2^nt\right)$, $r_0\left(1+t\right)=r_0\left(t\right)$, $r_0\left(t\right)=1$ for $0\leq t\leq 1/2$ and $r_0\left(t\right)=-1$ for $1/2<t<1$. Then:
$$\int\limits_0^1\left|F\left(t\right)\right|^2dt=\sum_{N_1}^{N_2}\left|b_n\right|^2\text{.}$$
In case there is a mistake, $\leq$ would suffice my needs as well.

I would say my problem is how to take the square from outside the sum to inside. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. I give it a simplified example to show the logic.

Let $x$ and $y$ be arbitrary and $F\left(t\right)=xr_n\left(t\right)+yr_m\left(t\right)$, for some $n$ and $m$. As a property of Rademacher functions, any pair divides the unit interval into 4 parts of equal length where each part has $F\left(t\right)$ equal to $x+y$, $x-y$, $-x+y$ or $-x-y$. Naturally, $\left|F\left(t\right)\right|$ is at each part $\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|$, $\left|x\right|-\left|y\right|$, $-\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|$ or $-\left|x\right|-\left|y\right|$. Now:
$$\int\limits_0^1\left|F\left(t\right)\right|^2dt=\frac{1}{4}\left(\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}\left(\left|x\right|-\left|y\right|\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}\left(-\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}\left(-\left|x\right|-\left|y\right|\right)^2=\left|x\right|^2+\left|y\right|^2\text{,}$$
as desired.

Comment: Well, I found out it's actually more simple that this. The Rademacher functions are orthonormal in (0,1), so the result I wanted is straightforward with this information.